# Does area51 system smart enough to know I am BAD at cooking?

Tags: discussion, area-51

"[Food and Cooking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking)" has 7% complete commitment status, by the time I am writing this.

I have tried to add a commit, but its does not increase at all, and remains 7%. I also tried 3 times uncommit, commit.

But [WordPress Answers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers), also has 7% complete, but when I commited, Its get 9%, and also tried 2 times by uncommit, commit.

So, the system smart enough to know I don't know anything about cooking and also knows about I have some knowledge on wordpress?

Comment: *Maaaaagic!* :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! It is a new system in Area 51 that is being tested there before being rolled out to other sites. Using patented eddy current technology along with geolocational IP info, it can trace down where you live and read the current contents of your harddrive as well as seeing the electrical currents of your brain. Using a special proprietary algorithm they judge if you know what you are talking about the subject.

Soon, reputation will be replaced by this system.. But if anyone asks, you didn't hear it from me

Comment: The good news is that if you can just provide us with your ip info, login details, and SSN, we can remotely deploy software to your machine to foil this invasion of your privacy.  And if you add your banking info, a temporarily illiquid member of the royal family in a misspelled African nation will send you a large sum of cash.

Comment: @jay +1 just for "illiquid"